# How to re-download Yosemite for creating second partition?

Tags: partition, macos

I have a paid Apple Developer account, and want to create a Beta-Partition with Yosemite.

I thought the way is pretty straight forward:

1. Downloading Yosemite
2. Install it
3. Choose second partition

But I cannot even download it from the App Store. I am on OS X 10.10.2 and want to try 10.10.3.

[image]

**How can I create a Beta Partition after already having 10.10.2 installed?**

If I boot in recovery mode and re-download Yosemite, will it delete my hard drive? Can I re-download and then choose my second partition?

Answer (score 1):

When you go to the purchases-tab OS X Yosemite should show up with a Download button. When you click it it asks you if you want to re-download it event though it is installed. (Downloading from the purchases tab is different from downloading from the product page I believe.)

Comment: Look at my screenshot. This message is from the purchases tab)

Comment: That's weird. It works for me.. Alternatively you could use your Recovery Partition for the 2nd install I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the YosemiteBetaAccessUtility.pkg?

Access via the [Apple Beta Program](https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/welcome)
You'll need to sign in or create an account to get to that link.

You can't get to the betas without it.
Your error message looks like the one you would get if you just tried downloading the current Yosemite release again.

Answer (score -1):

This is another scenario that illustrates why creating USB install media is a good idea, as opposed to simply downloading and running the installer. Link to instructions for creating a USB installer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/175227/84989).